# keyval being picky about empty options

Tags: expl3, key-value

I am trying to automate the generation of beamer handouts, with the help of `\pgfpagesuselayout`. I want them with 2 slides on 1 page, my colleagues with 4 in landscape orientation. So we generate both versions, by compiling the file with different jobnames and a conditional in our class that changes behaviour when the jobname contains `-HANDOUT` or `-HANDOUT4`. Note that `\pgfpagesuselayout` uses portrait by default, and does not have a `portrait` option, only `landscape`.

I initialise to 2 on 1 by default :

```
\str_const:Nn \g__chato_beamer_slides_per_page {2~on~1}
\str_const:Nn \g__chato_beamer_orientation {}
```

When the right circumstances arise, I change that to

```
\str_gset:Nn \g__chato_beamer_slides_per_page {4~on~1}
\str_gset:Nn \g__chato_beamer_orientation {landscape}
```

In the end, I say

```
\pgfpagesuselayout{\str_use:N\g__chato_beamer_slides_per_page}[a4paper,\str_use:N\g__chato_beamer_orientation,border~shrink=5mm]
```

In 4 on 1 mode, this works well. In 2 on 1 mode, I get

```
! Package keyval Error:  undefined.
```

It seems not happy with an empty option. So I tried integrating the `a4paper` part into the variable. But then, in 4 on 1 mode, I get

```
! Package keyval Error: a4paper,landscape undefined.
```

I know I could work around that, by having a conditional to make separate calls to `\pgfpageuselayout`, or by reverting to my first solution but setting

```
\str_const:Nn \g__chato_beamer_orientation {a4paper}
```

(I get no complains about the repeated `a4paper` option)

However, does anyone understand why `keyval` seems so picky ? What is going wrong, specifically, with my `a4paper,landscape` option ? Is this a bug ?

Comment: unrelated but you shouldn't use \str_const for a variable that you plan to change. A constant is a constant, not a variable.

Comment: This looks like an expansion problem, use `\use:e { \exp_not:n { \pgfpagesuselayout } { \g__chato_beamer_slides_per_page } [ a4paper, \g__chato_beamer_orientation,border~shrink=5mm ] }` instead and see what happens.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree in principle, and was almost disappointed I did not get an error from that. But how can I define a variable to a value ? ``\str_new`` then ``\str_set`` ? It's bizarre that there is no ``\str_new:Nn`` to define a non-empty value.

Comment: Please note that in `expl3`-naming conventions, the type of a variable should be part of its name (as a suffix), like this: `\g__chato_beamer_slides_per_page_str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyval` is so picky, because it tests for emptiness by using

```
  \KV@@sp@def\@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
```

and in case of your `\str_use:N \g__chato_beamer_orientation` this isn't `\@empty`. Then it uses the contents of the key in `\csname` (which will try to build a key with an empty name, since your `\g__chato_beamer_orientation` is empty) and tests whether the result is `\relax`, if that's the case (it is, the empty key name isn't defined) you get an undefined key error via `\PackageError` which fully expands `\@tempa` and hence also your `\str_use:N`, and you see the empty message.

To store multiple keys and values inside of your macros (or none, in fact, everything different from a single key without a value) you need to expand your strings before `keyval` does its parsing. That can be done with `\use:e` for instance (`expl3`'s `\exp_args:N...` is not really applicable for you because of the optional argument). So the following should work (but obviously I couldn't test it, you show no compilable example):

```
\use:e
  {
    \exp_not:n { \pgfpagesuselayout }
      { \g__chato_beamer_slides_per_page }
      [ a4paper, \g__chato_beamer_orientation, border~shrink=5mm ]
  }
```

Note that for strings you can omit `\str_use:N` if you want to.

Comment: ``\exp_args`` not being usable is due to each character of the optional argument (including [) being seen as one token ?

Comment: Correct, well, we could trick it a bit, e.g., `\exp_args:NVNe \pgfpagesuselayout \g__chato_beamer_slides_per_page_str [ {a4paper, \g__chato_beamer_orientation_str, border~shrink=5mm} ]` (since `[{}]` is the same as `[]` in most parsings of optional arguments). But you'd have to generate that `\exp_args:N...` variant, I guess.